# Copy file using hexdump and hexedit

Tags: python, linux, hexdump, hex-editors

I have a binary that has to be copied over serial port to the device that has hexedit installed.

How to get hex dump of the binary on Linux (preferably in Python) in a format that can be simply inserted into hexedit?

Comment: Not sure what the real question is here. You want to copy a binary file over serial. Fine, copy it. Then you want to load it into `hexedit`. Fine, use `hexedit FILENAME`.

Comment: Target machine is UEFI so it does not really have any software like cat that would allow me to copy the file. On the other hand it has hexedit so I can use it to copy the file. Question is how to get hex dump of a file on source that I can paste into an empty file opened in hexedit on target.

Comment: How about `xxd -c 16 -g 1 YOURFILE` ?

Comment: You can strip the address at the start of the line by piping through `cut -d\  -f2-`

Comment: Or `od -An -v -t x1 YOURFILE`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more thing that was needed to do was to remove all new lines and spaces.

Comment: Oh! If you want it like that, use `xxd -p YOURFILE` to get a *"plain"* hexdump.

Comment: I did not know what I want because I was not aware what data should I insert into hexedit. So correct answer is plain hexdump without spaces and new lines. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool... I'll write it as an answer for all to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating the question a little, I think you want to generate a hex dump of a binary file on one machine and save it in the clipboard, then start `hexedit` on a different machine and paste the clipboard into `hexedit` - thereby transferring a binary file.

So, let's generate a recognisable, small PNG image which is a binary file, just using **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc:red -strip image.png
```

Now look at in hex:

```
xxd image.png
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 0040 0000 0040 0103 0000 0090 a7e3  ...@...@........
00000020: 9d00 0000 0350 4c54 45ff 0000 19e2 0937  .....PLTE......7
00000030: 0000 000f 4944 4154 28cf 6360 1805 a380  ....IDAT(.c`....
00000040: 7c00 0002 4000 018c c5ab 7700 0000 0049  |...@.....w....I
00000050: 454e 44ae 4260 82                        END.B`.
```

That looks good, but we don't want all the address offsets down the left side, or the ASCII on the right side or the spaces and newlines, so we can use a *"plain"* dump:

```
xxd -p -c0 image.png
89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000004000000040010300000090a7e39d00000003504c5445ff000019e209370000000f4944415428cf63601805a3807c0000024000018cc5ab770000000049454e44ae426082
```

If you don't have `xxd`, you can use `od` instead, something like this:

```
od -An -t x1 image.png | tr -d ' \n'
```

And now we want to get that into our clipboard so we can paste it into the `hexedit` on the remote machine. The command will vary between operating systems.

On macOS:

```
xxd -p -c0 image.png | pbcopy
```

On Linux, something like:

```
xxd -p -c0 image.png | xsel --clipboard
```

Or:

```
xxd -p -c0 image.png | xclip -sel clip
```

Then go to the remote machine, create an empty file called `pasted.png`, start `hexedit` and paste into the file, and save:

```
> pasted.png ; hexedit pasted.png
PASTE
Ctrl-X
```

**PASTE** is probably <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd>, or middle mouse button, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

It looks like this in `hexedit`:

[image]

Now open the (binary) file to check it:

```
xdg-open pasted.png
```

[image]